# Select The First Item In A RadComboBox

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I'm trying to get a RadComboBox to select the first item in a result set but have not been able to do so. I have asked the Telerik folks and they can't get it to work either. I have a demo project available for download here:

https://rcpt.yousendit.com/1110087085/647dc0d8e5ed4f6763d1ab5e270f8c6b

If I type 'purchas' in the input field, I want 'purchasability' to be highlighted since it's the first item in the result set. The next thing I want to have happen is to press the [enter] key in order cause a postback. Since 'purchasability' should be selected, the RadComboBox1.SelectedValue should be 405, which is displayed in a label after the postback. Please note that none of these operations involve using the mouse to select an item in the result set.

Comment: Here is a post on Telerik asking the same question. They suggested not using RadComboBox. Take a look:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/combobox-and-listbox/selecting-first-item-in-radcombobox.aspx

Comment: That question is for WinForms. My question pertains to ASP.NET client-side scripting.

Comment: I finally got working code from Telerik. I posted a solution [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/how-to-emulate-facebook-search-behavior-using-a-radcombobox.aspx#1637369)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, when you add EmptyMessage the combo box will not select the first item by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I do not see how you expect to output the selected value in the combobox using the button click server handler in your scenario. Either get the client instance of the button inside the panel and invoke its click() method or set AutoPostBack = true for the combo and wire its SelectedIndexChanged event to modify the label text. For the latter and I am not sure how this will work with client load-on-demand with web service for the combobox.

Comment: This is only a half answer and would have been more appropriate as a comment, especially because of its snarky tone.